# JavaScript keypressed only working when text field contains ';'

Tags: javascript

I want the textbox to disappear when I type in text and press enter. But it for some reason only disappears when I type in ';'. Any other characters seem to not work.

```js
function enterPressed(e, field) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("searchbox");
        eval(tb.value);
  if (field.value.length > 0) {
 document.getElementById('searchdisappear').style.display='none';
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  <script src ="./js/search.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>

<!-- SEARCH BAR AND BUTTON -->
 <div id="searchdisappear" style="display:block;">
  <input id="searchbox" class="search" maxlength="200" type="text" onkeypress="enterPressed(event, searchbox)" placeholder="Search.."/>
  <p class="searchtext" onclick="buttonClicked(searchbox)"

 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: As a notice, using eval in most cases is a bad idea.  Never trust user input.

Comment: Why are you calling `eval` on a string that originated from the user?  This is a bad idea.

Comment: I tried your snippet and it works exactly as what you wanted. Just that eval() would fail the script if you type anything non-numeric, non-statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone! All sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove unnecessary `eval` function.

```js
function enterPressed(e, field) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (field.value.length > 0) {
 document.getElementById('searchdisappear').style.display='none';
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  <script src ="./js/search.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>

<!-- SEARCH BAR AND BUTTON -->
 <div id="searchdisappear" style="display:block;">
  <input id="searchbox" class="search" maxlength="200" type="text" onkeypress="enterPressed(event, searchbox)" placeholder="Search.."/>
  <p class="searchtext" onclick="buttonClicked(searchbox)"

 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Its always good to _explain_ an answer and why it works.  Not everyone can immediately see why.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: @Daedalus Sorry, I usually answer first with snippet and then update with the explanation.

Comment: That's okay! I can tell from what you wrote what the problem was. I was using eval. There was no need for an explanation on something so short. @Daedalus No need for a downvote! :)

Comment: Both of you, here's another good tip:  Don't immediately assume those who commented, voted.  For one thing, I have yet to vote on this answer or question.